# I'm trying to get download url of attachment from email using imap

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, imap, email-attachments

I'm using Laravel Package for IMAP EMAIL CLient and i'm getting email with attachments but i'm trying to get download url of attachents.

I'm using the laravel-imap package.

Please if any one can answer me to get download link I will be thankful to you.

Thanks

Comment: When you do this `$aAttachment = $oMessage->getAttachments();` Try `dd($aAttachment);` and see what you get!

Comment: i'm getting attachments content as well but unable to decode attachment and generate download url

Comment: Search for `getImgSrc` in that documentation you will get it.

Comment: if i have other file type then how will i download the file by clicking

Comment: You should go through `Attachment::class` from that documentation once.

Comment: <a download href="data:<?php echo base64_decode($attachment->content); ?>

i'm trying to download file like this